# Framer Motion Infinite Carousel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm trying to make an infinitely scrolling carousel of images (each with the same dimensions) in framer motion, but I can't get it to work properly. I want it to smoothly display images moving at the same speed without any breaks, and when it gets to the end of the chain, it should start again with the first image.

If I play with the duration or x position settings, then each item in the carousel moves at a different speed and it breaks.

If I add a delay to the start of each item, I did get each item to move in uniform, but then theres either a flicker in the spawning or a bald point with no items.

Here's my code:

```
const ExoticImage = React.forwardRef<HTMLImageElement, ImageProps>(
    function ExoticImageWrapper(props, ref) {
        return <Image {...props} ref={ref} />;
    }
);

const MotionImage = motion(ExoticImage);

type ImageUrlAlt = {
    url: string;
    alt: string;
};


function CarouselItem({ i, index }: { i: ImageUrlAlt; index: number }) {
    const x = useMotionValue(1);
    const controls = useAnimationControls();

    const pic = (
        <MotionImage
            style={{ x }}
            src={i.url}
            height={500}
            width={500}
            alt={i.alt}
            animate={controls}
            className="rounded-lg drop-shadow-lg"
        />
    );

    useMotionValueEvent(x, "animationComplete", () => {
        console.log(index);
        controls.set({ x: 1250 });
        controls.start({
            x: -1250,
            transition: {
                ease: "linear",
                duration: 5,
            },
        });
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        controls.set({ x: 1250 });
        setTimeout(() => {
            controls.start({
                x: -1250,
                transition: {
                    ease: "linear",
                    duration: 5,
                },
            });
        }, index * 1000);
    }, [pic]);

    return pic;
}

function Carousel({ images }: { images: Array<ImageUrlAlt> }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex space-y-3 xl:space-y-0 xl:space-x-3 items-center justify-center flex-col xl:flex-row">
            {images.map((i, index) => (
                <CarouselItem i={i} index={index} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've tried playing with all sorts of settings and none of them produce the proper result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i think,
You need to co-ordinate the animations of all the items in the carousel.

- The "x" value for each item is initialized to '0' instead of '1'. Let the "x" value for each item is initialized with'0' instead of '1'.

```
const x = useMotionValue(0);
```

- In the event handling for animationComplete, reset the `x` value to `totalItems - 1` instead of '1250'.

```
useMotionValueEvent(
  x,
  'animationComplete',
  () => {
    controls.set({ x: totalItems - 1 });
    controls.start({
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: 'linear',
        duration: 5,
      },
    });
  },
  [controls, totalItems]
);
```

- Add dependency array to the `useEffect` hook to include all the variables (`controls`, `index`, and `totalItems`) used inside the effect.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  controls.set({ x: totalItems - 1 });
  setTimeout(() => {
    controls.start({
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: 'linear',
        duration: 5,
      },
    });
  }, index * 1000);
}, [controls, index, totalItems]);
```

- Add `key` prop to each `CarouselItem`(for mapping).

```
{images.map((i, index) => (
  <CarouselItem key={index} i={i} index={index} totalItems={totalItems} />
))}
```